# Magento - Remove add new address option for customers

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Can somebody please help me remove the option for customers on Magento from adding a new address to their account or point me to the correct files, as i want this to be done by an admin only

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file path is:
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/address/book.phtml.

If you are using any theme then find in respected theme folder